# Define text value of class as global var, so it can be yield later in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I want to save text value of class defined inside object as global variable, so it can be yielded outside that object.

**What I mean on example - I got:**

`cy.get(".cat").eq(0).then(text => { let catTitleText = text; cy.wrap(catTitleText).as('catTitleText')});`

And I want to use this `let catTitleText` outside object for URL comparison, so like this:

`cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.config().urlLive+'faq.html?category='+catTitleText+[...]`

But Cypress will throw an error that `catTitleText` is not defined, which makes sense.

The only solution I've found needs invoking it, like this for example:

`cy.get('@catTitleText').then((text) => { function })`

But reason I don't want to do this way, is that I want to have multiple variables used inside `cy.url()` function, so my thinking is to define each variable globally, so those can be invoked in the same manner in `cy.url()`.

Maybe it can be done using invoking but different way in `cy.url()`, so multiple objects can be yield inside? Sorry if that description is chaotic or I mistaken something, I tried my best to describe it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Cypress.env()` for saving the text and then it can be used throughout your project.

```js
cy.get('.cat')
  .eq(0)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    Cypress.env('catTitleText', text) //Saving the cat title
  })

//Validate URL using Cypress.env
cy.url().then((url) => {
  cy.wrap(url).should(
    'eq',
    Cypress.config().urlLive +
      'faq.html?category=' +
      Cypress.env('catTitleText')
  )
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I can yield defined value using cy.log(Cypress.env('catTitleText')) inside '.then' brackets, but outside it - it becomes undefined. I tried some other methods but without success.

Comment: Updated the answer. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it an .alias() and use it in junction with `function() {}` and `this` keyword.

```
before(() => {
  cy.get('.cat')
    .eq(0)
    .invoke('text') // get text of element
    .as('cat') //store as alias
})
// use function() {} to be able to use this keyword
it("some test", function() {
  // some more actions

  // get alias using this keyword
  cy.url().should('eq', Cypress.config().urlLive + 'faq.htmlcategory=' + 
     this.cat + ...)
})
```

Comment: I'm almost sure accessing the alias in such a way will not work. The `cat` alias is not yet resolved when it's referenced via `this.cat` expression. You need to call it under a `then` or other callback that will let Cypress time to execute the command and assign a value to this alias

Comment: Right. I forgot to move the alias into a before/beforeEach.